# How to obtain all request headers in Go

Tags: go

How can I obtain all available http headers from a request as array in Go? I see only the following two methods:

- Header(name string, value string)
- GetHeader(name string)

But in this case I need to know the name of the Header and can't return all existing headers. I'd like to copy the http headers from one request to anther one.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use [Request.Header](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.Header) to access all headers. Because Header is a map[string][]string, two loops are required to access all headers.

```
// Loop over header names
for name, values := range r.Header {
    // Loop over all values for the name.
    for _, value := range values {
        fmt.Println(name, value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use above approaches if you want to loop one by one through all headers. If you want to print all headers in one line you can,

```
if reqHeadersBytes, err := json.Marshal(req.Header); err != nil {
    log.Println("Could not Marshal Req Headers")
} else {
    log.Println(string(reqHeadersBytes))
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As you can see from [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header), `Header` is just a `map[string][]string` with some extra helper methods, so you can still use it like any `map` to access its keys:

```
for key,val := range req.Header {
    // Logic using key
    // And val if you need it
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and explanation. I understand it now. Your tip was the solution.